# GitHub action runner with containerd - /var/run/docker.sock not found error

Tags: docker, containerd, github-actions

I'm running a GitHub self hosted action runner which uses the `docker` cli but the host I am running it on is using `containerd` as the runtime. `docker` is installed, except there is no active `/var/run/docker.sock`. How can I fix this so GitHub action runners work?

```
pi@kube-master:~ $ sudo find / -name "docker.sock"
```

```
pi@kube-master:~ $ sudo find / -name "containerd.sock"
/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

```
pi@kube-master:~ $ docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    25.0.3
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.12.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.24.5
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

Comment: The docker daemon isn't running. `sudo systemctl status docker`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, when `containerd` was installed and upgraded the `docker` systemd service was disabled.

Simply doing `sudo systemctl enable --now docker` fixed the issue.